# how to run a javascript on page load

Tags: javascript

I tried almost everything. A script count how many users are in group. I must find out how open this script on page load and upgrade reload. here is this script:

```
 <script>
var userCollection;

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
//Get all groups in site
var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
// Get the group by name
group = groupCollection.getByName('Sharepoint Group');
//Get all SP Users in SP Group
 userCollection = group.get_users();
clientContext.load(userCollection);  
//Execute Query
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded1), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 


function onQuerySucceeded1() {
    alert(userCollection.get_count());
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=userCollection.get_count();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


</script>
```

Comment: Its work when I edit page and don't work when I reload this

Comment: Are you using the ScriptEditor Web Part? If yes, when the script does not work, does the URL contain "_layouts/15/start.aspx#"?

Answer (score 1):

It may be trying to execute before the SharePoint client object model JavaScript library (aka "SP.js") has finished loading. This would cause your code to fail when it reaches "SP.ClientContext()" because "SP" would be undefined.

Try wrapping it up in a call to ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded.

Example:

```
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var userCollection;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    //Get all groups in site
    var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    // Get the group by name
    group = groupCollection.getByName('Sharepoint Group');
    //Get all SP Users in SP Group
     userCollection = group.get_users();
    clientContext.load(userCollection);  
    //Execute Query
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded1), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)); 

    function onQuerySucceeded1() {
        alert(userCollection.get_count());
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=userCollection.get_count();
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
},"SP.JS");
</script>
```

Comment: It don't work too

Comment: :(Can You try at Your Sharepoint please ?

Comment: What version of SharePoint do you have (2010 or 2013)?

Also, how are you adding the JavaScript to your page?

Comment: Yes i, m add ING to my page and I use Sharepoint 2013.

Comment: Try using F12 developer tools and debugging your JavaScript to see what the error might be.